# Thread reusal in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool

I have a code in Android, which is resource intensive. It processes a bitmap and then saves it to the sdcard.

Since running it on the main thread took a lot of time, I did it like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      //do work
    }
  }).start();
```

But, I found that if I invoked this piece of code before the thread had fully executed, the previous thread just got deleted and overwritten with the new task. The sdcard showed only the last image.

So I wrote a static thread as :

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //do work
        }
      };
```

But, t.start() cannot be called multiple times. (llegalThreadStateException)

What should I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning a second thread using the code you gave above will work and run both threads in parallel. Something else must be going on to stop it working.

Make sure you have a try-catch around your do work and log any errors. Are both threads trying to write to the same file and the second one failing because it cannot?

For the actual thread you cannot start a thread again once it has exited, instead you need to keep the thread alive and run it in a loop. The thread should go to sleep when it is no longer needed, waiting for a message to arrive giving it new work to do. This can be done using something like a `BlockingQueue`.

Alternatively rather than managing threads yourself you can use something like a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and keep sending your `Runnable`s to that.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but my image save location is IMG+ (currenttimeinmillisecs)+.jpg. Does getting the current time inside a thread have to do anything with the overwriting?

Comment: Found the error. I was using the class global variables inside the thread causing them to b ovrwritten with the latest value. Updated code with local variables. Worked fine. Thanks!